# Time complexity (How is this O(n))

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am having trouble understanding how this code is O(N). Is the inner while loop O(1). If so, why? When is a while/for loop considered O(N) and when is it O(1)?

```
int minSubArrayLen(int target, vector& nums)
{

   int left=0;
    int right=0;
    int n=nums.size();
    int sum=0;
    int ans=INT_MAX;
    int flag=0;
    while(right<n)
    {
        sum+=nums[right];
        if(sum>=target)
        {
            while(sum>=target)
            {
                flag=1;

                sum=sum-nums[left];
                left++;
            }
        ans=min(ans,right-left+2);
        }
        right++;
    }
   if(flag==0)
   {
       return 0;
   }
    return ans;
}
};
```

Comment: What is `N` even? In any case, you could argue that the size of the vector (if that's what is `N`) is bounded, so anything is O(1) anyway. Still, please format your code and share _your_ thoughts on the question, just to demonstrate that your not trying to get around doing your own homework.

Comment: tell us your justification of what you think is right.

Comment: Assume that first loop runs forever. Try figure out how many times `left++;` can be invoked in such case? It will turn out `N`! Note `left` is flowing `right`. Range moves like caterpillar.

Answer (score 1):

Both the inner and outer loop are O(n) on their own.

But consider the whole function and count the number of accesses to `nums`:

The outer loop does:

```
    sum+=nums[right];
    right++;
```

No element of `nums` is accessed more than once through `right`. So that is O(n) accesses and loop iterations.

Now the tricky one, the inner loop:

```
            sum=sum-nums[left];
            left++;
```

No element of `nums` is accessed more than once through `left`. So while the inner loop runs many times in their sum it's O(n).

So overall is `O(2n) == O(n)` accesses to `nums` and `O(n)` runtime for the whole function.

Comment: how is it o(2n) and not o(n^2)?

Comment: @superfly let `n=10` then `2n == 20` and `n^2 == 100`. Repeat for 20, 30, 40, 50. They behave nothing like each other. Why do you think those two would be the same?

Comment: And careful with your shift key: The agorithm is `o(1)` but `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Outer while loop is going from 0 till the n so time complexity is O(n).

O(1):
int sum= 0;
for(int x=0 ; x<10 ; x++) sum+=x;
Every time you run this loop, it will run 10 times, so it will take constant time . So time complexity will be O(1).

O(n):
int sum=0;
For(int x=0; x<n; x++) sum+=x;
Time complexity of this loop would be O(n) because the number of iterations is varying with the value of n.

Comment: saying that the complexity is O(n)  just because the outer loop runs n times isn't exactly right, you have to justify the inner loop as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Consider the scenario

The array is filled with the same value `x` and  `target` (required sum) is also `x`. So at every iteration of the outer while loop the condition `sum >= target` is satisfied, which invokes the inner while loop at every iterations. It is easy to see that in this case, both `right` and `left` pointers would move together towards the end of the array. Both the pointers therefore move `n` positions in all, the outer loop just checks for a condition which calls the inner loop. Both the pointes are moved independently.

You can consider any other case, and in every case you would find the same observation. 2 independent pointers controlling the loop, and both are having O(n) operations, so the overall complexity is O(n).